# Select a subset of a dataframe based on conditions : category and note

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, subset

I am trying to Select a subset of a dataframe where following conditions are satisfied:

- for same category keep only the row with highest note,
- if category=na keep the row

Here's my dataframe example :

[image]

The expected result:

[image]

What is the efficient way to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with mask chained [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with bitwise `OR` for missing rows by same column:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['category_id','note'])

df1 = df1[~df1.duplicated(['category_id'], keep='last') | 
           df1['category_id'].isna()].sort_index()
print (df1)
   book_id category_id  note
1      id2          c1     5
4      id5         NaN     1
5      id6         NaN     7
6      id7          c2     6
7      id8          c3     2
8      id9         NaN     8
9     id10         NaN     4
10    id11         NaN     9
```

Or use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `range` (necessary non integers in `category_id`) and then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
s = df['category_id'].fillna(pd.Series(range(len(df)), index=df.index))

df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(s)['note'].idxmax()].sort_index()
print (df1)
   book_id category_id  note
1      id2          c1     5
4      id5         NaN     1
5      id6         NaN     7
6      id7          c2     6
7      id8          c3     2
8      id9         NaN     8
9     id10         NaN     4
10    id11         NaN     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting has a O(n*logn) complexity, so better use a linear time approach when you can.

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two masks:

```
# is the row a NA?
m1 = df['category_id'].isna()
# is the row the max value for a non NA?
m2 = df.index.isin(df.groupby('category_id')['note'].idxmax())
# or if you want to keep all max rows if several
# m2 = df['note'].eq(df.groupby('category_id')['note'].transform('max'))

# keep if any condition is met
out = df.loc[m1|m2]
```

output:

```
   book_id category_id  note
1      id2          c1     5
4      id5         NaN     1
5      id6         NaN     7
6      id7          c2     6
7      id8          c3     2
8      id9         NaN     8
9     id10         NaN     4
10    id11         NaN     9
```

##### how does it work?

Here are the intermediates for the boolean masks, ultimately only the rows with `True` in the last mask are kept:

```
   book_id category_id  note  is na?  is max?  is either?
0      id1          c1     2   False    False       False
1      id2          c1     5   False     True        True
2      id3          c1     3   False    False       False
3      id4          c2     4   False    False       False
4      id5         NaN     1    True    False        True
5      id6         NaN     7    True    False        True
6      id7          c2     6   False     True        True
7      id8          c3     2   False     True        True
8      id9         NaN     8    True    False        True
9     id10         NaN     4    True    False        True
10    id11         NaN     9    True    False        True
```